# C: Resultado de delta, x1 e x2 sempre dando 0,000000

Tags: c, matemática

Estou aprendendo C na faculdade, e estou empacado com esse algoritmo. Não consigo encontrar o erro.
Ele consegue diferenciar se delta é maior ou menor que zero, mas sempre imprime delta, x1 e x2 como 0,000000

```
   /*
    Name: Bhaskara
    Date: 10/08/17 19:30
    Description: Escreva um algoritmo que calcule a formula de bhaskara. 
    O Algorismo deve atender a condição do delta:
    D = 0, a equação tem duas raizes iguais
    D > 0, a equação tem duas raizes diferentes
    D < 0, a equação tem duas raizes reais
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    float a, b, c, delt, x1, x2;


    printf("Digite o valor de a: \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Digite o valor de b: \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Digite o valor de c: \n");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    delt = b*b -4*a*c;
    printf("Delta = %f \n", &delt);

    if (delt >= 0) {

        x1 = (-b + sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
        printf("x1 = %f \n", &x1);
        printf("x2 = %f \n", &x2);
    }

        else {
        printf("A equação não tem raizes. \n"); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para entender seu erro você precisará de uma explicação sobre o operador **&** (í comercial) ou (e comercial).
Este operador em linguagem C significa: **endereço de memória de**...

Portanto, se você colocar este operador na frente de alguma variável ele irá retornar o endereço que a variável esta alocada na memória RAM.

Como sabe, as variáveis ficam alocadas na memória e por isso, possuem um endereço no qual é utilizado para acessar este conteúdo.

Na programação básica de linguagem C, sem uso de ponteiros, para acessar o conteúdo de uma variável basta escrever o nome desta variável e compilador se encarrega de achar o endereço dela e trazer ou escrever algo dentro da variável.

No caso da função **scanf** ela precisa saber o endereço da região de memória da variável para poder colocar o que é digitado via teclado, dentro da variável.

No seu caso:

```
printf("Digite o valor de a: \n");
scanf("%f", &a);
```

Acima a função **scanf** irá obter o valor digitado pelo usuário e colocar no endereço da variável a. A função scanf espera receber este endereço de memória da variável e por isso, você precisa colocar o **&** na frente de a ficando **&a** (isso se chama passagem de parâmetros por referência e você vai estudar quando ver o assuntos funções)

Já a função **printf** **não espera** que você coloque este **&**. A função printf precisa apenas do nome da variável para obter o conteúdo que está dentro dela e mostrar este conteúdo na tela, desde que você especifique seu tipo (%d, %f , %c, etc).

Experimente, por exemplo, colocar **%p** ao invés de %f e veja que o resultado mostrado na tela, será o valor do endereço de memória que as variáveis delt, x1 e x2 ocupam.

*Obs: %p indica que você deseja a saída formatada como um endereço de memória*

[image: Endereço das variáveis]

Observe o código com **%p**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    float a, b, c, delt, x1, x2;


    printf("Digite o valor de a: \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Digite o valor de b: \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Digite o valor de c: \n");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    delt = b*b -4*a*c;
    printf("Delta = %p \n", &delt);

    if (delt >= 0) {

        x1 = (-b + sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
        printf("x1 = %p \n", &x1);
        printf("x2 = %p \n", &x2);
    }

        else {
        printf("A equação não tem raizes. \n");
        }

return 0;
} /* fim main*/
```

Observe que agora aparece o endereço de memória das variáveis. Está aparecendo no seu código 0,00000 pois você formatou um float %f na saída de um endereço de memória que deveria ser formatado como %p.

Veja agora mais abaixo o seu código corrigido e os resultados. Lembrando que **%.0f** indica que é para não termos casas decimais após a vírgula de um número real(float)
Se fosse **%.2f** indicaria que você deseja duas casas decimais após a vírgula. e Por ai vai...

[image: Delta e Raizes]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

float a, b, c, delt, x1, x2;


printf("Digite o valor de a: \n");
scanf("%f", &a);

printf("Digite o valor de b: \n");
scanf("%f", &b);

printf("Digite o valor de c: \n");
scanf("%f", &c);

delt = b*b -4*a*c;
printf("Delta = %.0f \n", delt);

if (delt >= 0) {

    x1 = (-b + sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(delt))/(2*a);
    printf("x1 = %.0f \n", x1);
    printf("x2 = %.0f \n", x2);
}

    else {
    printf("A equação não tem raizes. \n");
    }
return 0; 
}
```

Pronto! Agora funciona! Estude os conceitos da linguagem C pois irá te ajudar muito! Anote suas dúvidas e não hesite em perguntar! Abraço!

Lembre-se: **H**errar é **U**mano! :)

Answer (score 1):

Você está dando print no endereço de memória das váriaveis `&delt, &x1, &x2`. 
O correto seria apenas `delt, x1, x2`

Answer (score 1):

O & antes de uma variável indica que vc está buscando o endereço desta e não o conteúdo, por isso que na hora que vc recebe um dado vc utiliza o &variavel pois esta guardando aquele dado no endereço da variável, mais quando imprime vc deve chamar apenas a variável pois nesse momento vc quer o conteúdo.

```
printf("Delta = %f \n", &delt); =fica=> printf("Delta = %f \n", delt);
```

e o mesmo se aplica para as outras impressões

Se quiser entender melhor o conteúdo lhe indico estudar ponteiros, serão de grande utilidade.